# Uploading File using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient - WinRT 8.1 PCL

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, win-universal-app, system.net.httpwebrequest

```
I have a requirement of uploadng the file to Server in Win8.1 PCL project. 
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. 
I tried in Advanced Rest Client and it works fine
PFA @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8cv5.png

I have the Code like this. 

     Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, uri);

     HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
     streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
     streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
     streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + flKey + "\"; filename=\"" + fleNm + "\"");
     request.Content = streamContent;

     var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
     var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
     Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await   httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(cts.Token);
     String resp = response.Content.ToString();
```

This is not working. Pls le me know whats wrong with the Code, why this code is not able to write the file to the server.

```
Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: Can you explain what about it isn't working? I.E. is there an exception, or is the server rejecting the POST, or is the request body empty, or...?

Comment: Code is Fine. There is no exception, I get the response Status Code 200 but Yes Server  rejecting the Post. May be of two reasons 1. Request Format is wrong 2. File Stream is not Writing properly. How can I Tace this ?

Comment: If you're running on Windows, I recommend trying Microsoft's Message Analyzer tool; it's basically Wireshark but works better on Windows than Wireshark does (can capture loopback, etc.). If on another platform, use Wireshark. Capture the request and see what's happening. Alternatively, look at the incoming request from the server side. By the way, if the server rejects the POST request it really shouldn't be returning status 200; that means the request succeeded.

Comment: Ya response is 200 but the message sent in Wrong format, may be missing something. Using Fiddler to trace and will check with Message Analyzer Tool as well. Thanks :)

Comment: #CBHacking Could you pls help me to use this Message Analyzer Tool to trace my Request as this is the first time I am using it. :)